# How to send channel_session data from outside the consumer class

Tags: django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am facing problem in sending data from channel_session outside the consumer class.

My consumer is like :-

```
class myconsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    #all init connect function

    def subscribe(self):
        self.channel_Session = payload['data']

    #some other functions
```

Now the problem is, I want to send this self.channel_session through an async function which is called as a thread.

```
async def sendData():
    while True:
        #send data
        await asyio.sleep(5)

class thread(multiprocess.Process):
     try:
         loop = asyncio.bew_event_loop()
     except Exception as e:
          loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(sendData())
```

This Thread is started on starting the server.

## Question

I cannot find a way to send that channel_session

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First use `get_channel_layer()` to get the active layer that communicates with redis, then call `group_send` to invoke a consumer method specified by the `type` argument.

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

async def sendData():
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    while True:
        await channel_layer.group_send(
            << your_group_name_here >>,
            {
                'type': 'subscribe',
                'message': 'custom message'
            }
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```